# SVNKit use of auth folder

Tags: java, svnkit

I'm using `SVNKit` (1.8.4) to retrieve logs (only the logs) from different repositories, on different servers, with different protocols. The whole thing runs on a `Tomcat` server and is querying each `SVN` server every 2 minutes for changes.

After a lot of trial and error, I came up with a scheme where I make a folder for each `SVN` client instance, so that it can store all the credentials etc. in its own isolated place.

Here's the relevant code that creates the `SVNRepository` object:

```
SVNRepository getRepository(String url,
                                String authFolder,
                                    String username,
                                        String password)
                                            throws SVNException {
    SVNRepository repository =
        SVNRepositoryFactory.create( SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url) );  
    ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager =
        SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(
                      authFolder, username, password, true);
    repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    return repository;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: take a look here: http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/Accessing-credentials-ISVNAuthenticationProvider-authenticationProvider-td175549.html

Comment: @logoff the link you sent describes more or less the same problem, and doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use lightweight BasicAuthenticationManager instance in place of DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager one. BasicAuthenticationManager only users in-memory credentials and doesn't use local settings or configuration files.

The code would look like that:

```
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = 
  new BasicAuthenticationManager(new SVNAuthentication[] {
        new SVNPasswordAuthentication(userName, password, 
                                      false, url, false),
  });
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
```

Comment: While using DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager the code execution continues even when I enter the wrong password in Windows machine.. On linux machine i get the error mentioned in this URL "issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-290"; Will your code solve that problem??