# SVNKit authentication error E170001, but only when checking out and only on one computer

Tags: java, linux, svnkit

I'm completely stumped by an SVNKit (1.8.5) error that I'm running in to.  I'm using the following pattern to build up an Authentication Manager:

```
public static SVNRepository getSvnRepository(String userName, String pass, String repoURL) throws SVNException
{
      SVNRepository repository;
      repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(repoURL));
      ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(userName, pass);
      repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

      return repository;
}
```

I use this pattern in several places to make sure that the user can authenticate against the repository, to get a listing of all of the folders in the repository, and even to explore the top level of the subfolders in order to parse a file and build up a dependency graph.  All of this succeeds.

But when I attempt to run a checkout, I get an authentication error.  Puzzlingly, this error only happens on one computer at our office.  Several other computers all running OS X, Windows, and various versions of Ubuntu take no issue with this process and can check out no problem but one particular computer running Ubuntu 12.10 fails hard trying to run the following:

```
SVNRepository repository = getSvnRepository(userName, pass, url + "/" + subfolder);
SvnOperationFactory factory = new SvnOperationFactory();
SvnCheckout checkout = factory.createCheckout();
checkout.setSource(SvnTarget.fromURL(repository.getLocation()));
checkout.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(location.resolve(project).toFile()));
checkout.run();
```

The stack trace:

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Authentication required for '<https://[snip]:443>'
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:47)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:41)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:186)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:682)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:371)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:359)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:710)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:627)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:102)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1032)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:175)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:118)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:182)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:45)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:756)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:16)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:10)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1149)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
```

Comment: Maybe on that particular machine, there is existing (and incorrect) authentication information in the `~/.subversion` folder, and your `DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager` instance tries to use that? See also the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403997/svnkit-use-of-auth-folder?rq=1

Comment: I am facing the same issue on a Windows 7 machine.  On this machine Eclipse, Ant, and svn command line can access the svn server at "https:"  with no issues.  Interestingly, other workstations work fine.  The stacktrace is not that useful.  Has anyone have any debugging suggestions?

Comment: Update:  I found something that helped my issue on Windows, kind of: http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/SVN-authentication-problem-td1560.html   I had to add a jvm argument:  -Dsvnkit.http.methods=Basic,Digest,Negotiate,NTLM

Answer (score 0):

I experienced an issue with this same backtrace recently in Windows. It puzzled me as I had successfully checked out content from other paths within my company via svnkit just fine and couldn't fathom why this specific path was choking via svnkit.

I grabbed the source of svnkit to assist with my debugging, and noticed that it was inspecting cached authentication details within the path "`C:\Users\gurcei\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\`".

Inside here was a file named "`870755ae945b...`" (probably a random number each time), and when I opened it within a text editor, I could see it contained credential details, and it also mentioned the domain-name/realm relating to these credentials.

I noticed that the file used a short domain-name, e.g.:

```
K 15
svn:realmstring
V 43
<https://subversionxy:443> Subversion Realm
```

This made the penny drop for me on why my failing checkout was choking via svnkit. I had accidentally provided a fully-qualified domain name for the path (e.g., `https://subversionxy.my.company.com/...`), and I think this meant svnkit couldn't find the credentials in the cache.

Upon switching to the short domain-name (e.g., `https://subversionxy/...`), the checkout worked for me.